# Marketing Cloud ( translation of Data Extension attribute value into different languages)

Tags: dataextensions

hope you can help me out please.

1. A user subscribe and purchase a product through a web form on the
   company website form 5 different countries with 5 different
   languages with a language field on the webform to indicate which
   country i.e GB , FI, DA, NO etc

   - The subscriber's data land in a Triggered send Data extension in MC (via API call) including the language field that I will be used
     to send out dynamic contents emails in that language for the
     subscriber.
   - I then have an email triggered and sent out to the subscriber which display the product price and product type (product types are
     ‘Monthly’ or ‘Annual’)
   - My issue here is that all emails triggered are sent out in their respective languages except the product type field which always
     comes in english i.e Monthly or Annual.
2. Data Extension fields as follow:
   SubscriberKey, EmailAddress ,firstName, password, freeTrialLength, productType, service, subEndDate , userid , language, transactionDate, surname, productPrice, totalTransactionAmount
3. Email is sent out in 5 different languages according to subscriber language in the Data extension. these languages are (GB,DA,FI,NO,SE)
4. Product type (‘Monthly’ or ‘Annual’). ***So the question is how to translate this product type value to their matching language that the email is sent out with ?***

I know it can be achieved by AMPScript but I tried having a go at AMPScript but failed. If you could provide your solution AMPScript code then that would be great.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What did you  try so far with Amp script  post here your code

Comment: Taken at off script as can't submit comments.This is me trying ampsript %%[VAR productType, language, monthlyEN, monthlyDA,annualEN, annualDA SETannualEN = "Annual" SET annualDA = "årlig" SET monthlyEN = "Monthly”SET monthlyDA = "Månedlige"IF language == “GB”  AND productType == “Monthly” THEN SET productType = monthlyEN 
ELSEIF language == “GB”  AND productType == “Annual” THEN SETproductType = annualEN
ELSEIF language == “DA”  
AND productType == “Monthly” THEN 
SET productType = monthlyDA 
ELSEIF language == “DA”  
AND productType == “Annual”THEN 
SET productType = annualDA ENDIF ]%%

Comment: @pkharries , I added my ampscript code as requested

Comment: @A Sh There's no automatic translation you will do with manually

Comment: What Error you getting post here

Comment: @pkharries, I don't get an error from the code but rather the product type in the email is still displaying what's in the data extension. Just wondering if there is any way by ampscript that I can read the attribute from the DE and then translate that attribute value into my email according to the language field in DE.